# Mach-O Linker Error linking to pods

Tags: xcode, linker

I am new to app development, but I am a seasoned developer in other languages. I've downloaded a sample project written in an older version of XCode than I'm using. It is linking through CocoaPods to AFNetworking and when I try and run the basic project before making further changes I get a Mach-O Linker error. I've tried several things I've seen on other threads and the project compiles with the same error every time. Can someone help please? Error is as follows:

Ld /Users/dickiebow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RWPuppies-dnhsukxxlqrjhzhiympqasxkyrsp/Build/Intermediates/RWPuppies.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RWPuppies.build/Objects-normal/i386/RWPuppies normal i386
    cd "/Users/dickiebow/Documents/XCode Projects/RWPuppies"
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk -L/Users/dickiebow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RWPuppies-dnhsukxxlqrjhzhiympqasxkyrsp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/dickiebow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RWPuppies-dnhsukxxlqrjhzhiympqasxkyrsp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/dickiebow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RWPuppies-dnhsukxxlqrjhzhiympqasxkyrsp/Build/Intermediates/RWPuppies.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RWPuppies.build/Objects-normal/i386/RWPuppies.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -framework Foundation -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=6.0 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -lPods -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/dickiebow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RWPuppies-dnhsukxxlqrjhzhiympqasxkyrsp/Build/Intermediates/RWPuppies.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RWPuppies.build/Objects-normal/i386/RWPuppies_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/dickiebow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RWPuppies-dnhsukxxlqrjhzhiympqasxkyrsp/Build/Intermediates/RWPuppies.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RWPuppies.build/Objects-normal/i386/RWPuppies

ld: library not found for -lPods
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the CocoaPod Architectures being out of sync with the main project. Once they were all set the same the project compiled successfully. This article was very helpful. http://www.schiffhauer.com/debugging-xcode-and-cocoapods-architecture-issues/