# Linker Error with Pod

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have a project which is using some CocoaPods to manage some external libraries.  My project was working fine when I was just using two libraries (EstimoteSDK and EstimoteIndoorSDK).  But, I modified my podfile to add the [**Alamofire library**](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire).  My podfile looks like this:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
pod 'EstimoteSDK'
pod 'EstimoteIndoorSDK'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 1.1'
```

After I run 'pod install', I can see the added Alamofire folder... so I assume all went well.  I then open my *project.xcworkspace* file and try to build my app... but I get an **Apple Mach-O Librarian Error** stating that there is an '**unknown option character 'X' in : -XLinker**'.  Nothing really changed in my project from before... except for installing the Alamofire pod... and this error is indeed linked to the Pod-Alamofire project but I don't really know what it means.  I have seen [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26466173/mach-o-linker-error-linking-to-pods), but it doesn't seem to be the issue as the Architectures of both the Main project and the pods are set to "Standard architectures (armv7, arm64)". Does anyone know why I keep getting this error?

Comment: Can you check the otherlinkerflags in build settings for the reported flag?

Comment: In the pods build settings, the other linker flags section is empty.  In the main project build settings, the other linker flags section has '-lc++'.  Should the pods build settings contain the flag 'X'?

Comment: I went back to the terminal to re-do the installation, and I noticed this warning: 

`[!] The Project [Debug] target overrides the OTHER_LDFLAGS build setting defined in Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.debug.xcconfig. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the $(inherited) flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.`

I'm not entirely sure what this means or where I'm supposed to put the $(inherited) flag.  Would this be causing the issue?

Comment: try Deleting the `pods-xconfig..` file in your project and try installing the pod again?

Comment: Ok.  I added a '$(inherited) flag in the main project other linker flags and then deleted the pods-xconfig files (both release and debug).  Then, I reinstalled the pods and got a clean install (no warnings).  I then re-open the workspace file and try to build, but I still get the warning.  The error is definitely linked to the Pods-Alamofire project but says there is some unknown option character 'X' in -Xlinker.  But, for the life of me I can find no flag 'X' in the entire project.  Any other ideas?

Comment: What is the version of pods you are using?

Comment: Well, I used the command `sudo gem install cocoapods --pre` to get the latest version which I think is 0.36 beta.  I then re-ran the installation and it seemed to work ok... although weirdly my bridging-header.h file disappeared from the project.  After, reestablishing that (and making sure the paths were correct)... now, I'm getting an error saying Linker command failed with exit code 1.  The Alamofire error seems to be gone, but a new one is there.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you detail on linker failed with exit code 1, is there some other Message with that?

Comment: Well, it looks like it's having trouble finding EstimoteSDK library (but not the IndoorLocationSDK... which is weird).  Here's the error:

`ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/me/Desktop/Dev/Indoor Positioning/../../EstimoteSDK'
ld: library not found for -lEstimoteSDK
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

The thing is, I don't know where I'm supposed to tell it to look for that. Under the Project>Build Phases>Headers... I can see all of the header files but all of the EstimoteSDK headers are red.  Thoughts?

Comment: Can you check whether your pods are build ? (clean + clear Derived data) --> try building and check whether the pod build status is displayed..

Comment: Thanks Naveen for your patience.  That didn't really work either... so I decided to start over from scratch.  Once I did, and re-ran the installation with all 3 pods... it now builds as expected.  Honestly, I don't know what could have been the issue.  But, thank you for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem a few days ago. The commands below fixed my problem.

First uninstall the cocoa pods by using the command below:

`gem uninstall cocoapods`

After, reinstall the cocoaPods library with the following code below

`gem install cocoapods --pre`